# Modifying My Image Uploader

Tags: php, codeigniter

At this present point in time I have some code that does the following:

I can edit and I can add a house sale that uploads/edits one image for this particular house and then during the process a thumbnail is created and then the original file name and the thumbnail name is saved to database fields called **imagename** and **imagethumb**.

(*Note: Add and Edit a seprate pages*)

What my idea is:

I will create another page that has the name of the houses fed into a dropdown menu so when one is selected and images are selected they will upload.

What my issue is:

1. I am getting myself confused as to what would be the best way to modify my database to enable this change.
2. How would I modify my php code to handle more then one file (How do I handle multiple images and then pass the image for uploading resizing etc ) What is the best option? - within my given idea?
3. Could I have an example of what I should do so I can work off this.

I have included the model view and controller (As an **Example**) of my Add Sale but I will also need to edit a image for the respective sale.

**Model:**

```
class Sales_model extends CI_Model
{

    function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
    }

    function getSalesPage($id = NULL) {

        $query = $this->db->get_where('sales', array('id' => $id), 1);
        if($query->num_rows() == 1) return $query->row();

    } # End getSalesPage

    function getSalesPages($id = NULL) { // $id does nothing
        $query = $this->db->get('sales');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) return $query->result();

    } # End getSalesPages

    function getSalesContent($id = NULL) {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('sales', 1);

        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->result_array();
            return $row;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        } # End IF
    } # End getSalesContent


    function addSale($data = NULL) {
        $this->db->insert('sales', $data);
        return TRUE;
    } # End Add Sale    

    function updateSale($id, $content) { //Content id from being passed

        $this->db->where('id', $id);  // selecting the $id to update
        $update = $this->db->get('sales'); // What does $update = well it = get the db sales
        $row = $update->row_array(); // what does $row mean = well it gets the row as an array

        if($update->num_rows() > 0) {

            if(isset($content['imagename']) && isset($content['thumbname'])) {

            #lets delete the image
            unlink("/includes/uploads/gallery/".$row['imagename']);
            #lets delete the thumb.
            unlink("/includes/uploads/gallery/thumbs/".$row['thumbname']);
        }
                $this->db->where('id', $id);
                if($this->db->update('sales', $content))
                {

                    return TRUE;
                }
                else
                {
                    return FALSE;
                }
            } # End IF
    } # End Update

    function deleteSale($id){

        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $q = $this->db->get('sales');
        $row = $q->row_array();

        if ($q->num_rows() > 0){
            //delete from the database
            $this->db->where('id', $id); 
            $this->db->delete('sales');

            //lets delete the image
            unlink("includes/uploads/sales/".$row['imagename']);
            //lets delete the thumb.
            unlink("includes/uploads/sales/thumbs/".$row['thumbname']);
        }//END if num_rows
    }//END function deleteSale($id)
} # End Model
```

**View:**

```
    <?php
//Setting form attributes
$formAddSale = array('id' => 'addSale', 'name' => 'addSale');
$saleName = array('id' => 'name', 'name' => 'name','class' => 'validate[required[custom[onlyLetterSp]]]', 'value' => set_value('name'));
$saleLocation = array('id' => 'location', 'name' => 'location','class' => 'validate[required[custom[onlyLetterSp]]]', 'value' => set_value('location'));
$saleBedrooms = array('id' => 'bedrooms','name' => 'bedrooms','class' => 'validate[required[custom[number]]]', 'value' => set_value('bedrooms'));
$saleBathrooms = array('id' => 'bathrooms','name' => 'bathrooms','class' => 'validate[required[custom[number]]]', 'value' => set_value('bathrooms'));
$saleCondition = array('id' => 'condition','name' => 'condition','class' => 'validate[required[custom[onlyLetterSp]]]', 'value' => set_value('condition'));
$saleImage = array('id' => 'userfile', 'name'=> 'userfile');
$salePrice = array('id' => 'price','name' => 'price','class' => 'validate[required[custom[number]]]','value' => set_value('price'));
$saleDescription = array('id' => 'description','name' => 'description','class' => '', 'value' => set_value('description'));
$saleSubmit = array('id' => 'submit', 'name'=> 'submit', 'value' => 'Add Sale');
?>

<div id ="formLayout">
    <?php
    if($success == TRUE) {
    echo '<section id = "validation">Sale Added</section>'; 
    }
    echo '<section id = "validation">'.$message['imageError'].'</section>';
    ?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/addsale/', $formAddSale); ?>
<?php echo form_fieldset(); ?>

<?php echo form_label('Name:','name'); ?>
<?php echo form_input($saleName); ?>
<div id="errorName"><?php echo form_error('name'); ?></div>
<span class="small">Required Field - Text</span>

<?php echo form_label('Location:','location');?>
<?php echo form_input($saleLocation);?>
<div id="errorLocation"><?php echo form_error('location'); ?></div>
<span class="small">Required Field - Text</span>

<?php echo form_label('Bedrooms: ','bedrooms');?>
<?php echo form_input($saleBedrooms);?>
<div id="errorBedrooms"><?php echo form_error('bedrooms'); ?></div>
<span class="small">Required Field - Number</span>

<?php echo form_label('Bathrooms: ','bathrooms');?>
<?php echo form_input($saleBathrooms);?>
<div id="errorBathrooms"><?php echo form_error('bathrooms'); ?></div>
<span class="small">Required Field - Number</span>

<?php echo form_label('Condition: ','condition');?>
<?php echo form_input($saleCondition);?>
<div id="errorCondition"><?php echo form_error('condition'); ?></div>
<span class="small">Required Field - Text</span>

<?php echo form_label('Price: ','price');?>
<?php echo form_input($salePrice);?>
<div id="errorPrice"><?php echo form_error('price'); ?></div>
<span class="small">Required Field - Number</span>

<?php echo form_label('Image: ','userfile');?>
<?php echo form_upload($saleImage);?>
<div id="errorUserfile"><?php echo form_error('userfile'); ?></div>
<span class="small">Required Field - 1MB Max Size</span>

<?php echo form_label('Description: ','description');?>
<div id="errorDescription"><?php echo form_error('description'); ?></div>
<span class="small">Required Field - Text</span>
<?php echo form_textarea($saleDescription);?>
<script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace('description');</script>

<?php echo form_submit($saleSubmit);?>
<?php echo form_fieldset_close(); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
class Addsale extends CI_Controller 
{ 
    function __construct()
    { 
        parent::__construct(); 
    } 

    function index() 
    { 
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))redirect('admin/home');

            # Main Data

            $data['title'] = 'Add Sale: ';

            //Set Validation

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'trim|required|xss_clean'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('bedrooms', 'Bedrooms', 'trim|numeric|required|xss_clean'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('bathrooms', 'Bathrooms', 'trim|numeric|required|xss_clean'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('condition', 'Condition', 'trim|required|xss_clean'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'trim|required|xss_clean'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

            if($this->form_validation->run()) {
            //Set File Settings 
            $config['upload_path'] = 'includes/uploads/sales/'; 
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png'; 
            $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
            $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
            $config['max_size'] = '1024';
            $config['max_width'] = '1024'; 
            $config['max_height'] = '768'; 

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) {

                $data['message'] = array('imageError' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            } // Upload error end
            else{
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    $data['success'] = TRUE;
                    $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';
                    $config['source_image'] = $this->upload->upload_path.$this->upload->file_name;
                    $config['new_image'] = 'includes/uploads/sales/thumbs/';
                    $config['create_thumb'] = 'TRUE';
                    $config['thumb_marker'] ='_thumb';
                    $config['maintain_ratio'] = 'FALSE';
                    $config['width'] = '150';
                    $config['height'] = '150';

                    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                    $this->image_lib->resize();


                $file_info = $this->upload->data(); 

                $this->db->escape($content);

                $content = array(   
                    'name' => $this->input->post('name', TRUE), 
                    'location' => $this->input->post('location', TRUE), 
                    'bedrooms' => $this->input->post('bedrooms', TRUE), 
                    'bathrooms' => $this->input->post('bathrooms', TRUE), 
                    'condition' => $this->input->post('condition', TRUE), 
                    'description' => $this->input->post('description', TRUE), 
                    'price' => $this->input->post('price', TRUE), 
                    'imagename' =>$file_info['file_name'],
                    'thumbname' =>$file_info['raw_name'].'_thumb'.$file_info['file_ext']
                );          

                $this->sales_model->addSale($content);
                }#end else
                } # End Form Validation       
                $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/addsale', $data, TRUE);
                $data['sales_pages'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages();
                $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
                $this->load->view('admintemplate', $data);

            } # End Index Function 
        } # End Controller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For handling dropdown, i think its easy one. But related multi upload stuff, you can use something like...

in your view

```
<?php echo form_label('Image: ','userfile1');?>
<?php echo form_upload('userfile1');?>
<?php echo form_label('Image: ','userfile2');?>
<?php echo form_upload('userfile2');?>
<!-- and so on -->
<span class="small">Required Field - 1MB Max Size</span>
```

Then in your controller, you can do this way

```
//Set File Settings 
$config['upload_path'] = 'includes/uploads/sales/'; 
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png'; 
$config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
$config['max_size'] = '1024';
$config['max_width'] = '1024'; 
$config['max_height'] = '768'; 

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

// Validate files for upload section...
$success = array();
$errors = array();
$updload_files = array(
        'userfile1' => $_FILES['userfile1'],
        'userfile2' => $_FILES['userfile2'],
        // You can add more
        );

foreach($updload_files as $field => $updload_file)
{
    // Only process submitted file
    if($updload_file['error'] == 0)
    {
       // If there is an error, save it to error var
       if( ! $this->upload->do_upload($field) )
       {
           $errors[] = 'Failed to upload '.$field;  
       }

       // Use this to get the new file info if you need to insert it in a database
       $success[] = array( 'Success to upload '.$field => $this->upload->data());
    } 
    else 
    {
       $errors[] = $field . ' contain no data';  
    }
}
// Heres you could gettin know whats happen
var_dump($errors);
var_dump($success);
```